Is this rig improperly connected to its attached model or is this normal?
I was experimenting with the Trifecta add on--you know, the one with the TF2 characters for Source Filmmaker-type animations--when I noticed this:

When I grabbed the green line bone, which I assumed moved this sniper's arm, it moved perfectly fine, but the model didn't move with it. (If I were to grab the blue bones as well as the green ones, it simply rotates the individual pieces of the arm and distorts it rather than bending.)
This is what it looks like unmoved, I have hidden all except the green bone to show its default position (and those small orange ones aren't a part of the limb at all):

For those of you familiar with the add-on and its included rigs, it has nothing to do with the cosmetic item I have on the character; if there's a problem, it's with the base model, and isn't specific to this particular one. I haven't tested all nine included models/armatures, but the ones I have tested have the same problem.
Is this just me not understanding how these rigs work? I'm very new to animating but thought I was decently familiar with IK rigs, which is what the identifiers in the corner say these ones are. But if this isn't me and is a genuine issue with the armatures, it would be best to let their creator know about this.

If this model was rigged with Rigify (which it looks like it was) then it has two separate "sub-armatures" in the same armature; one for FK and one for IK which is enabled by default. The green one is the FK rig. If you look in the N panel in Pose mode under the Item tab you should see a panel labeled Rig Main Properties where you can see all the controls for that.  There's a slider for FK->IK influence per bone, and buttons that snap one set of bones to the position of the other so you can use both in concert.

More info on this page of the docs.

Thank you, I’ll have to remember that. I don’t know much about FK rigs or how Rigify works, so I wasn’t aware that there were technically two separate armatures that can work in tandem.

Saying there are two armatures or even "sub" armatures is a recipe for unnecessary confusion 
These are not different armatures, it's just two sets of bones that you interact with differently.
Rigify features
As Jakemoyo explained, Rigify features both FK and IK (see Rigify Features Description — Blender Manual.
You can toggle the IK and FK bones independently for each limb from the sidebar > Item tab > Rig Layers panel.
And by selecting any of a limb's IK or FK bones, you will also have access to its IK/FK properties in the Rig Main Properties panel allowing you to switch using IK or FK, snap your IK controlles to or from the FK ones, ...

FK vs IK
FK (Forward Kinematics) involves rotating each joint individually from the root to the tip, creating a naturally sequential movement, while IK (Inverse Kinematics) lets you move the tip of a chain (like a hand or foot), with the bones of the "chain" from root to tip adjusting automatically to reach the position. FK is often used for arcs in arm swings or anything that requires predictability and precision of the whole chain, while IK is preferred for grounded actions like a foot on the ground during character lean or for very straight motions like a punch of mechanically constrained movements like a hand sliding on a table.

There's a nice video that explains it pretty entertainingly: Animating ARMS (FK vs. IK) - Doodley - YouTube

oh this is very helpful. and the animation you have right there is making sense of the weird spheres I was noticing didn't do anything when I pulled at them.
